# Grub, Windows Boot Manager and BIOS

Tags: boot, grub2, windows, lubuntu, ubuntu-mate

I currently have a desktop with three hard drives, a 120GB SSD, a 1TB HDD and a 2TB HDD. On my SSD I'm running Lubuntu, the 1TB HDD has Windows 10, and the 2TB HDD has Ubuntu MATE.

When I power on and press F12 I see PC-Linux-OS, Ubuntu, and my drives.

For context, I started out with my SSD with Lubuntu on it. Later on I installed Windows 10 to my 1TB HDD. After installing Windows I noticed it did not add a boot entry, however after updating grub on Lubuntu, Windows Boot Manager was located within the Ubuntu boot entry. Then I tried to install PC-Linux-OS to my 2 TB HDD, for some reason I could not get it to work, but it added a boot entry for it (which couldn't boot). So after some deliberation I downloaded and installed Ubuntu MATE onto my 2TB HDD, but the PC-Linux-OS boot entry is still there.

I'm trying to remove the PCLinuxOS boot entry, and separate the Windows Boot Manager from grub so that it has its own separate boot entry (default). Windows and the two Linux OSs are all on separate hard drives and I want to make my boot menu reflect that.

Also I've been trying to figure out how to move Windows 10 to my SSD (which has Lubuntu on it), and Lubuntu to the 1 TB HDD (which has Windows on it). I saw a few questions and guides that used Clonezilla and Tuxboot, but I'm not really confident with trying this yet. I feel as though if I clone my Windows HDD to the SSD with Lubuntu in it, I wont be able to boot Windows due to the fact that the Windows Boot Manager is inside grub.

Specs:

- mobo: Gigabyte z87-ud3h
- CPU: Intel i5 4690k
- SSD: Samsung 128GB (sda1/2/3 with Lubuntu)
- HDD: Seagate 1TB (sdb1 with Windows 10)
- HDD: Seagate 2TB (sdc1/2/3 with Ubuntu MATE)

Boot Info Summary: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/16338254/

recommended repair summary http://paste.ubuntu.com/16354671/

Comment: Are all systems UEFI with gpt partitioning on all drives? But may be best to see details:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: I have edited my OP with the boot info summary.

Comment: Your Windows on sdb, must boot thru the ESP - efi system partition on sda. Windows only boots from gpt partitioned drives with UEFI. And both sda & sdb are gpt. Windows normally also has a 128MB system reserved which must be before the main install on drive. Not sure how to move a Windows install as you should not use dd to copy gpt partitions. I would expect one of the Windows based clone tools to work, but that really is a Windows forum issue.  And grub chain loads to the entry in the ESP.  You also can directly boot from UEFI. Be sure to turn fast start up off before anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, 1 year and 8 months ago I asked a stupid question. I suppose for the integrity of the site I'll give my stupid answer..

First of all, to remove the old boot entries in your BIOS load screen, (I haven't figured out how to do this using Windows, I usually use a live image of Ubuntu) open a terminal and enter:

`sudo apt-get install efibootmgr
 sudo efibootmgr
 sudo efibootmgr -b (bootcode) B`

Be careful not to delete the wrong one!

Next, I had 3 hard drives with 3 different OS' on them. I installed a bunch of Linux distros and later installed Win 10 on the drives.

So the issue I had was with Grub and Windows Boot Manager. The problem here happened because I installed Windows on a another drive AFTER the other distros. To avoid this I wiped clean and started with Windows 10, ensured it had boot priority in my motherboard's BIOS settings. Then I installed the other distros after. This way Windows Boot Manager didn't end up in Grub (which was forcing me to go through multiple boot selection screens every time I powered on).

I hope this proves useful to at least 1 person :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Boot-repair to solve the issues of bootloader.

Install it by using following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

You can even manage your all grub bootloader entries using BCDEdit by neosmart.

BCDEdit:
https://neosmart.net/wiki/bcdedit/

Comment: Ok so I've tried pretty much everything I could find.

After using Boot-repair, BCDEdit, Efibootmgr, etc. I reinstalled Windows 10 on fresh hard drive, with all my other drives unplugged. This installed the Windows boot loader to the MBR. Unplugged that drive, plugged in another, and installed Arch with MBR/BIOS. 

Finally I can boot directly to either OS respectively to my mobo's boot sequence.

Now to just get rid of this damn Ubuntu entry in my BIOS menu. I can't get EFIbootmgr to work on Arch (since I installed it as MBR/BIOS), and EasyBCD only sees the Windows entries.